# Shell script that prints out the word "Directory" for all directories

Tags: bash

I need to write a shell script which looks at the contents of the current directory and for all directories prints out the word "Directory" followed by the name of the directory and a comma-separated list of the directory's contents sorted by modification time and for all files prints out the word "File" and the name of the file.

I guess it should be written by using echo command and a for loop which iterates all files in a directory but have no idea how to do it.

```
#!/bin/sh

for x in *
do

done
```

Comment: Maybe you can use this and take it from there: find . -type f -exec stat --printf " F: %n" '{}' \; -o -type d -exec stat --printf "\nD: %n" '{}' \;

Answer (score 0):

This small script will help you.

```
for x in `ls $(pwd)/` 
do
    if [ -d $x ]
        then echo $x
    fi
done
```

Explanation:

1. `for` loop in some directory. Here, in `pwd`.
2. Checking if the item is directory using `-d`.
3. Printing.